# Polynomials factor Theorem

Tags: polynomials

If a cubic polynomial $p(x)$ with leading co-efficient 1 is divided by $x-1$, $x-2$ and $x-3$ respectively it leaves $r(x)$ $1$, $4$ and $9$. What will be the remainder when it is divided by $x-4$?
I've searched for this everywhere but I couldn't find an answer. 
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a bog standard polynomial interpolation problem, or a standard chinese remainder theorem problem. Surely your textbook talks about these in the very chapter it asks this problem?

Comment: Actually, it isn't in any of the textbooks or guides that I own. That's why I asked the question here.

Comment: Are you sure you gave us all hypothesis? There are infinitely many answers, not just one.

Comment: Do you have the leading coefficient?

Comment: yeah, I'm pretty sure that this is all the information that my teacher gave.

Comment: I'm sorry whats a leading coefficient?

Comment: The coefficient of $x^3$ in this case. If you follow my solution, you will find that $p(x)=A(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+x^2$. $A$ can be any constant. So, there are infinitely many answers.

Comment: oh okay, I'll check and clarify.

Comment: Can you please tell us what is it that you do not understand within the answer provided by CY Aries? It seems very clear to me. And please do not write in all caps. That's the equivalent of shouting, and I don't think that we deserve that.

Comment: Sorry. It's just so frustrating.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand how we can write fx as px - x2?

Comment: @PrakharNagpal What CY Aries did was to *define* $f(x)$ as $p(x)-x^2$, which is a natural choice, since $p(k)=k^2$ for each $k\in\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=p(x)-x^2$. Then $f(x)$ is a cubic polynomial.

Note that $f(1)=p(1)-1^2=1-1=0$, $f(2)=p(2)-2^2=4-4=0$ and $f(3)=p(3)-3^2=9-9=0$

$f(x)$ has roots $1$, $2$ and $3$. So,

$$f(x)=A(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$$

for some constant $A$.

$$p(x)=A(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)+x^2$$

When $p(x)$ is divided by $x-4$, then remainder is

$$p(4)=6A+16$$

Without other information on $p(x)$, we cannot proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $$f(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\left(\dfrac A{x-1}+\dfrac B{x-2}+\dfrac C{x-3}+\dfrac D{x-4}\right)$$

Comment: Uhm, what is the meaning of the A, B,C and D??

Comment: @PrakharNagpal, Arbitrary constants